# Crear intent con el id de una lista

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, lista

Buenos días,
Espero que me podais ayudar. Estoy haciendo prácticas sobre Android, y estoy atascado en un capítulo sobre Activity e intents:

Tengo un List con varios elementos (lugares). Abro un cuadro de dialogo donde introduzco el id y se me abre VistaLugar, donde puedo ver la info del lugar.

El problema viene a la hora de abrir la actividad "EdicionLugar". En la práctica debo hacer que al apretar el botón Editar desde VistaLugar se abra la vista "EdicionLugar" pasandole el id del elemento qe estaba abierto en la actividad.

**

> Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.dks.mislugaresdomingo/com.example.dks.mislugaresdomingo.EdicionLugar}:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1

**

LA pregunta es: como le paso el id actual?(si es que es eso lo que esta fallando, claro)

**

```
public class VistaLugar extends ActionBarActivity {
    private long id;
    private Lugar lugar;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.vista_lugar);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    id = extras.getLong("id", -1);
    lugar = Lugares.elemento((int)id);

..............
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        ................
        case R.id.accion_editar:
            lanzaEdicionLugar((int)id);
            return true;

....



     public void lanzaEdicionLugar(int id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(VistaLugar.this, EdicionLugar.class);
        i.putExtra("id", id);
        startActivity(i);

    }
**
```

Pero no consigo resolver el problema. Cuando se ejecuta desde la otra vista VistaLugar este si recibe los parametros que se han introducido desde un AlertDialog:

```
public void lanzarVistaLugar(View view) { final EditText entrada = new EditText(this); ...... public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int witchButton){ long id = Long.parseLong(entrada.getText().toString()); Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VistaLugar.class); i.putExtra("id", id); startActivity(i);         
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { int id = item.getItemId(); if (id == R.id.menu_buscar) { lanzarVistaLugar(null); return true; }
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el mensaje de error más completamente? Tu error es causa de que intentas acceder al índice -1 de un Array, y en esa posición no hay nada. Mira en que línea marca el error, y pon algo más de código

Comment: He editado el post con algo mas de información

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas realizando un Intent desde la Activity `VistaLugar` para abrir `EdicionLugar`, si notas el error indica en donde se produce el problema, que es en la clase `EdicionLugar`:

> Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.dks.mislugaresdomingo/com.example.dks.mislugaresdomingo.EdicionLugar}:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1

El intent para enviar el id es correcto y se realiza sin problema:

```
public void lanzaEdicionLugar(int id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(VistaLugar.this, EdicionLugar.class);
    i.putExtra("id", id);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

**El problema es seguramente que al recibir `EdicionLugar` un indice `-1`, este indice no existe en un array de elementos, simplemente asegura enviar un indice valido!.**

---

Ok en la clase VistaLugar recibes un bundle con el id pero si no se tiene este valor, se obtiene por default el valor de -1,

```
id = extras.getLong("id", -1);
```

cambia el default a 0 para que sea un valor de indice valido:

```
id = extras.getLong("id", 0);
```

Comment: Correcto. Envía -1. Pero no consigo resolver el problema.

Comment: Para resolverlo simplemente envia un indice que no sea -1 , de donde obtienes este id  lanzaEdicionLugar((int)id); ???

Comment: Correcto. Envía -1. Pero no consigo resolver el problema.
Cuando se ejecuta VistaLugar este si recibe los parametros que se han introducido desde un AlertDialog:

  public void lanzarVistaLugar(View view) {
     final EditText entrada = new EditText(this);
......
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int witchButton){
                        long id = Long.parseLong(entrada.getText().toString());
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VistaLugar.class);
                        i.putExtra("id", id);
                        startActivity(i);

Comment: public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.menu_buscar) {
            lanzarVistaLugar(null);
            return true;
        }

Comment: pero donde llamas lanzaEdicionLugar() ?

Comment: Desde VistaLugar....onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    ................
    case R.id.accion_editar:
        lanzaEdicionLugar((int)id);
        return true;

Comment: He editado el post con algo mas de info

Comment: Ok, gracias, puedes resolver con lo que anexe a la respuesta,pero debes revisar porque no llega el valor de id a VistaLugar , esto cuando realizas el intent.

Answer (score 0):

Segun tengo entendido ese getLong -1 es para dar un valor cuando no exista, de manera que si no existe se cerrará la app.

La conclusión es que en estos casos saber usar el debugger es muy importante.
El problema radicaba en que estaba enviando valores null al objeto lugar desde un textView de la actividad.

Gracias por las aportaciones!